# Compute average trials to approach statistical probability?

Tags: probability

Is it possible to compute the number of trials required to get as close as possible to the statistical probability?

For example:

- Throwing a coin is 50 / 50, but how often do you actually have to throw a coin so the result really is 50/50
- Getting dealt two aces in a game of Poker the odds are 1 in 221, but how many hands do you have to be dealt so it really is 1 in 221?

I am not sure if my question is worded correctly, I hope it makes sense. Basically, to give an EXAMPLE answer that I am looking for:

You'd have to throw a coin at least 2700 times for it to equal out to 50/50, or you would have to be dealt 4595000 hands in poker for you to actually get two aces every 221 times.

I am not even sure if this can be calculcated. I guess one way to approach this would be to brute force this writing a little programm that iterates over coin flips as many times until it reaches 50/50 the first time, then repeat this process a couple thousand times and take the average of that?

Comment: Answer to the first question : The probability that the number of heads is equal to the number of tails after some number of throws is $1$, but paradoxically, the expected number of throws to achieve the tie, is infinite! For the second question : I guess that the probability is smaller than $1$ that the exact odd appears after some number of games.

Comment: Look at random walks and the results of Polya.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I just read http://www.askamathematician.com/2014/01/q-if-you-flip-a-coin-forever-are-you-guaranteed-to-eventually-flip-an-equal-number-of-heads-and-tails/, I think I might have asked an innocent question without realizing that there is no straight forward answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *finite* number of trials such that you are *sure* that the proportion of tails (or heads) is exactly 50/50. For any finite number of trials, the proportion of tails (or heads) is always a random variable. It can, by chance, be equal to 0.5 (for example, you try twice and you obtain one of each result), but there will always be incertainty. Even if you throw you coin 1 billion times, you may have a proportion of tails that is, for example, 0.500034.

However, when the number of trials increases, the probability that you get proportions far from 50/50 becomes smaller and smaller. That is, you'll never be sure to obtain exactly 50/50, but if you throw your coins enough times, you'll be very close to 50/50 with great probability. We can even compute these probabilities, using the central limit theorem.

Comment: A superb answer.